# What cone is the one I should use?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, finite-volume-method

I have this region:
$S={(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1 \wedge z^2\geq3(x^2+y^2) \wedge z \geq 0} \nonumber$

I need to determine the volume but I don't know  which cone should I choose.

[image]

[image]

Half of full cone?

Comment: Full cone above $z \geq 0$ - what you show in the first diagram.

Answer (score 0):

What you have sketched is correct.  Cone has $ 30^0$ semi- vertical angle.

Next the radius, height,  are $1/2, \sqrt 3/2$ respy:

$$ V = \pi \frac13 (\sqrt 3/2) {(\frac 12)}^2 $$